# How to debug Ginjector?

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin

I have a Ginjector:

```
@GinModules(FooGinModule.class)
public interface FooGinjector extends Ginjector {

  ...

  PlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler();

}
```

Whenever I call `injector.historyHandler()`, I get a null pointer exception. (The `injector` itself is not null.) How can I debug this? The error message printed to Chrome's console is not helpful - it just says "null pointer exception".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the `-gen` option to the dev mode or compiler so you can look at the generated code for the class implementing your `FooGinjector`.

If you're running in dev mode, you can even add the `-gen` folder to your *source path* in Eclipse and then step into the generated code during your debugging session.